# does map range do not capture attributes to transfer to group output?

Tags: node-editor, geometry-nodes

does the map range not have attributes that can be captured by the capture attribute node, I have been trying to capture attributes by the map range node so that I can view the displacement done through the group output node and feed it to a vertex group to view it in the weight map

[image]

Comment: the map range node doesn't capture anything, that's what the capture attribute node does. But i highly recommend providing at least your node tree so that we can help you. Even better would be a minimal .blend file. thx.

Comment: @Chris I have added the file.

Comment: Hi, Nishchay, I highly recommend, as well, describing/illustrating the specific example you have encountered, of the more general question you are asking. That means folks will get some kind of handle on it, before committing to a download.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

i recommend using the viewer node, to debug your node tree.

So i set the viewer node like this:

[image]

and looks for me ok, so proximity gives a good result.

Multiply doesn't harm either...

[image]

but the map range node doesn't look good:

[image]

you are mapping from 0 to negative 1.5...which makes less sense to me.

i changed your mapping node:

[image]

then put that result in the capture attribute node...

[image]

and put the result of capture to your group output:

[image]

weight paint result:

[image]

height map result:

[image]

hope, that helps.

Comment: so the problem was that i set it up incorrectly and nothing with the map range node

Comment: yep, that is correct